# Using Tab Bar Ios and Push and Pop another View Controller over it

Tags: ios, swift

Hi i am using Tab Bar for my Ios application (swift).

home page looks like this.

[image]

Now when i press the button i push  screen using story board reference.

This View controller in another storyboard

Screen looks like this

[image: This View Controller is in a separate storyboard]

On Pressing cancel i want to go back to Settings Screen (**More** Tab Selected)

How can i achieve that.

Comment: what is "Home Screen"? Do you mean just 1 step back to "Settings-Screen"?

Comment: yes i mean Settings-Screen . (question edited)

Comment: Have you tried : self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) ?

Comment: @Ondre_ yes this works. Thanks.

Comment: wow, I actually assumed that wouldn't work, since why would you ask a question for such an obvious answer?

Comment: @JohnnyAW yes, i am totally new in IOS development. new like fresh.. totally

Comment: well, have fun then, I actually liked it more than android development

Comment: @JohnnyAW Thanks, i want to perform this using uwind segue.. i followed the examples it is not working as expected any reference where i can learn this